# Change model values before process through actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-filters

How can I change sent data to controllers some where like OnActionExcuting?

Imagine I want develop a middle ware (something like asp.net attributes) replace all "a" to "A" and then bind values to model(in all action just can see "A"!)

Comment: You would need to create a custom `ModelBinder` (that's the point in the pipeline where binding takes place.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but if I don't want use it at all actions, how can I manage it with custom ModelBinder?

Comment: Far too broad to give you an answer. You will need to do some research but a few examples that use custom `ModelBinders` for converting posted form values to upper case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704818/uppercase-attribute-that-converts-the-input-to-uppercase) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cda5ba/model-binding-in-mvc-a-magical-mapper/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/andreabalducci/773608)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ModelBinder and use it on specific actions:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateSomething([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))] Something something) 
{

}

public class MyCustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Do something
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```