# How do I format a db string field to uppercase in either an mvc5 view or model. Cant get ToUpper to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Model:
 public Grade()

```
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string Grade1 { get; set; }
    public short? NoOfTeams { get; set; }
```

View:

```
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade1)
            </td>
```

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17840154/7073340) the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uppercase attribute that converts the input to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704818/uppercase-attribute-that-converts-the-input-to-uppercase)

Comment: Its just `<td>@item.Grade.ToUpper()</td>` (using `DisplayFor()` is unnecessary for a `string` property unless you have a custom `DisplayTemplate`). But why not just format it to upper case in the GET method (where it belongs)

Comment: Stephen - Would like to know how to format it to upper in the GET method please.

Comment: My solution so far is add this to Model:[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]|[0-9]{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Must be 1 uppercase character or 2 numbers")]
        public string Grade1 { get; set; }

Comment: and change View from  <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade1)
                </td>

Comment: to <td>
                    @item.Grade1.ToUpper()
                </td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Design First project (actually a conversion from Access) so my solution is to create Access queries and convert my data to uppercase during data conversion to SQL and then in MVC add the following to stop any new data being entered in lowercase:

Add to Model:
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]|[0-9]{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Must be 1 uppercase character or 2 numbers")] 
public string Grade1 { get; set; }

IE I wanted something simple.